# If compression socks increases the blood circulation and this is good for swelling, then how comes it is said ice is good for swelling?

Tags: blood-circulation, swelling, cold-compress, elevating-elevation

“Cold slows down blood flow to an injury, thereby reducing pain and **swelling**. Cold therapy slows circulation. It should be used if the area is **swollen** or bruised.”
“Compression stockings are used to help increase circulation. This helps swelling.”

How comes these two are true at the same time? I have reactive arthritis and my feet are swollen after long days especially when I stand up or walk a lot. I've read that poor blood circulation causes this and shifting between cold and hot water improves blood circulation. Normally I avoid hot water because it triggers my inflammation, it definitely makes it worse and cold is always good. Anyway, I tried it and I ended with ice compress after massaging in hot water. It didn't reduce swelling at all, it just made it worse. People also say that I should try compression socks for my swollen feet, but I am suspicious about it. If it increases the blood circulation it can't be good for me. Cold slows down the blood circulation and I know it is good for me. So, what is this all about poor circulation, swelling, inflammation, cold treatment thing? I can't make connection. Which one is good? Slowing down the circulation or increasing the circulation? Ice or compression socks? Elevating also is certainly good for me as I experienced.